# Error Message Upon Lid Reopen on Ubuntu 23.10 - Lenovo Legion Slim 5"

Tags: login, lenovo, 23.10

I recently purchased a Lenovo Legion Slim 5 laptop with a Ryzen 7 7000 series and an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060. I decided to install Ubuntu 23.10. Although the operating system generally works fine, I encountered an issue:

Every time I close the laptop's lid and leave it for a few minutes, upon returning, I am greeted with an error message ([see the attached image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0IqL.jpg)). This error forces me to log out, and upon logging back in, all my previously open applications and windows have closed, significantly interrupting my workflow.

Has anyone experienced something similar or has any suggestions on how to solve this problem? I appreciate any help or advice you can provide.

Thank you in advance.